# How can I set the java.library.path used by eclipse from a POM?

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, java.library.path

I'm using maven to define my projects. One of my dependencies requires a native DLL at runtime, and consequently it's needed in tests and for debugging. The native DLL is available at a known location. I want a solution that I can check in once and will work for all developers without manual setup by each dev.

I know I can set the java.libary.path manually in "run configurations", which will allow it to find the native DLL, but this requires manual setup for each developer.

I know I can also set the java.library.path for a given project dependency, but again this is local to a particular developer.

Finally I know I can set the surefire plugin to specify the java.library.path, but this is only useful for tests triggered via maven - so it's great for our build server, but doesn't help devs using the JUnit runner in eclipse, or wanting to debug or run code directly from eclipse.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that the eclipse m2e connector that goes with the [maven-nativedependencies-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mavennatives/) seems to fix this.

According to the mavennatives docs:

> Since version 0.0.7 of the maven-nativedependencies-plugin if you have
>   m2eclipse installed and the nativedependencies plugin configured the
>   unpacking of natives will run automatically, you don't need the
>   eclipse plugin to unpack them. However in order to setup the
>   java.library.path environment variable in eclipse you will have to do
>   it either manually or automatically using the eclipse plugin.
>
> This Eclipse plugin is an extension to m2eclipse, it detects if you
>   have the maven plugin configured, and if you do it executes the
>   unpacking of natives, and configures the Native Library Location.
>
> If you import a maven project that has the mavennatives plugin
>   configured, and you have the m2eclipse integration plugin, on import
>   the natives will be extracted, also when performing a clean from
>   eclipse the natives will be extracted.
>
> So, if you use both these tools, using native dependencies requires no
>   manual configuration, other than whats in the pom, just run your app
>   and it works.

If I have the connector installed, and add mavennatives to my POM, then reload the pom (right-click on project in package explorer > maven > update project), the "Native library location" of the project is populated automatically (to see this, right click on project > properties > java build path > libraries > native library location)

[image]

This seems to work for debugging, JUnit runner, etc.

It does require that every developer install the plugin, which is manual (as manual as installing eclipse); however, at least once installed once it will work for any/all native depdendencies configured for mavennatives via a POM.

Answer (score 2):

The [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) may help you passing the system properties by using [properties:set-system-properties](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) to set system properties.

The example should be look like the following: -

```
<properties>
    <java.library.path>some/path</java.library.path>
</properties>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: I don't think it helps. I already have some properties in my POM. The problem is getting eclipse, or the JUnit runner, to be aware of them. The doc you link for `set-system-properties` states "Requires a Maven 2.0 project to be executed." - I don't think this is happening while the JUnit runner is executing.